# Why do I have to add print function thrice in python i need to give print only once to get the output

Tags: python

i am trying to find mean, trimmed mean, and median from a dataset with file format .csv in python below is the code. My question is i am unable to get all values at once using print function just once i need to write print function thrice is there anything to shorten my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import trim_mean
f = pd.read_csv('E:\pop.csv')
print(trim_mean(f['Population'],0.1))
print(f['Population'].mean())
print(f['Population'].median())
```

Comment: `print` can take multiple positional arguments and prints each of them, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

pop = pd.read_csv(r'E:\pop.csv')['Population']
print(f'Trim mean={trim_mean(pop, 0.1)}, Mean={pop.mean()}, Median={pop.median()}')
```

Note the raw string notation

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
print(trim_mean(f['Population'],0.1), f['Population'].mean()),  f['Population'].median())
```

Even better, use f-string

```
print(f”Trim mean: {trim_mean(f['Population'],0.1)},   Mean: {f['Population'].mean()},  median: {f['Population'].median()}”)
```